# Is it necessary to have a perfect correlation when using linear regression?

Tags: linear-regression, correlation

I am working on predicting BMI against weight, using linear regression.

The scatter plot of the data can be found below.

[image]

As you can see in the plot, there seems to be low (or no) correlation between the two variables and thus I have doubts whether I'm using the right method. Is it necessary to have correlated data in order to use linear regression? Would you advice me to try other methods or adding features?

Comment: Welcome to Data Science! What would “perfect correlation” look like to you?

Comment: Isn't the function BMI(weight) already known? Why do you need to create a machine learning model instead of just using the formula?

Comment: @liakoyras it looks like you didn't understand the question kindly

Comment: @Dave, thanks so much, but I was looking for an answer kindly.

Comment: Then what do you mean by perfect correlation?

Comment: Yes, if I had understood it I would have posted an answer, thus I asked for some clarification in order to be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no correlation between variables you cannot run regression analysis as one variable cannot predict the other. Hence, it is necessary to have correlated data in order to run linear regression.